# SVN checkout into IDEs project folder

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, smartsvn

(I'm working with SmartSVN and VisualSVN Server)

I need to check out a project from subversion to the project-directory of an IDE.
the IDE can't open projects from anywhere (eg directly from the working copy) it only sees the projects in its projects folder.

I can't use the IDEs project folder directly as working copy directory, cause I need to have a working copy directory for each svn-url. (I get the error "../projects is already a working copy for a different url" when checking out a second project)

So, do I have to run a script that copies the files from wc to the projects folder? How is this triggered? (from SmartSVN)  this seems a little awkward....

How is this done best?

Comment: Is it possible to group projects together into one folder or does every project need to be in a separate folder which is contained in the project folder root? Maybe you could try checking out into subdirectories of the project folder.

Comment: Are there multiple 'projects' folders, or is there just one? Does it recursively find files (does /projects/project1 and /projects/project2 work)?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to check out a project into the IDE's project directory.  For example...

```
/project - the project directory for the IDE
/project/MyProject1 - First Project
/project/MyProject2 - Second Project
/project/etc - Other projects.
```

Basically, check each project out separately from SVN underneath the IDE's project directory.